# Apple Mavericks - why doesn't this one-line BASH script set my Python virtual environment like I expect?

Tags: mac, bash, python, environment-variables, bash-scripting

I have the following Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $MYPROJECT_HOME/bin/myproject_venv/bin/activate
source $MYPROJECT_HOME/bin/myproject_venv/bin/activate
echo $MYPROJECT_HOME/bin/myproject_venv/bin/activate
```

The permissions show that the file is executable, and it is owned by me.  The permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

When I run the script at the command line it twice prints the correct path to the `activate` script as I expect.  However, it does not correctly run the middle line - the one that sources the script.

If I copy that middle line and run it at the command line, however, it works fine.

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The issue

It is working perfectly (you can check this by adding an `echo` command to the sourced file), the problem is that it is run in a different shell. When you run a shell script (using bash as an example but the same ideas apply to other shells), it launches a non-login, non-interactive shell to run in. This means that a separate mini instance of `bash` is launched and *that* `bash` is the one that sources your script. That's why the variables you are setting are not present in the parent shell.

You can test this easily enough:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
export FOO="bar"
echo "FOO in test.sh is : $FOO"

$ export FOO="OOF"
$ echo $FOO
OOF                       ### Here, in the parent shell, $FOO is 'OOF'
$ ./test.sh
FOO in test.sh is : bar   ### In the shell running the script, $FOO is 'bar'
$ echo $FOO
OOF                       ### Back in the parent shell, $FOO is still 'OOF'
```

So, shell scripts are run in their own, separate shell and, as stated in `help source`:

```
source: source filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
```

So, `source` only affects the *current* shell which, in the case of a bash script is the one launched to run the script itself and not the parent shell where you typed the script's name.

---

#### Solutions

If you want to source a file that sets variables, you should do so from the shell you are running in, just run the `source` command directly.

Alternatively, you could have the `source` happen for all new shell instances by adding it to your `bash` startup file. This is `.profile` in OSX and `.bashrc` in most other cases. So, edit your `$HOME/.profile` file and add this line:

```
source $MYPROJECT_HOME/bin/myproject_venv/bin/activate
```

Now, all new terminals you open will have sourced the `activate` file. Or, if you want to be able to do this on demand, turn your script into a function. Add these lines to your `.profile`:

```
activate(){
  echo "Sourcing $TEST/activate"
  source $TEST/activate
}
```

Functions, unlike scripts, do not launch a new shell instance and, therefore, can modify the shell you launch them from. You can now run `activate` to source the `$TEST/activate` file.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that the script `activate` is running, but works by setting environment variables? If so, this could give you problems. As a test, I created two scripts, `command` and `activate`. The first is like your Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $TEST/activate
source $TEST/activate
echo $TEST/activate
```

and `activate` is a simple one-liner:

```
export TEST="Hello World!"
```

The output shows that changes to environment variables are not retained. Here's the commands I used to run this, and the results:

```
export TEST="/Users/me"
./command
```

This seems to change environment variables; here is the output:

```
/Users/me/activate
Hello World!/activate
```

But back at my command prompt, I can see that the value of $TEST is the same as before:

```
echo $TEST
```

has the output:

```
/Users/me
```

Maybe this is your problem?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the problem, or is closely related to the problem.  How can I get the bash script to have access to my environment variables and to be able to write to them?  I think that the script is running in some sort of new/fresh/different environment than the environment I am at at the command line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201363/invoking-a-bash-script-indirectly-and-a-puzzle-about-how-to-use-source-appro